# Installing Oracle Java 8 in Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: java, linux, java-8, linux-mint

After installing Oracle Java 8 in Linux mint, When I typed java --version on terminal it says

bash: /usr/bin/java: Permission denied.

Can I know why this is happening??

Comment: Change the access or owner of the catalog with `chmod` / `chown`.

Comment: You did not install it correctly. We don't know how you installed it.

Comment: 1.I downloaded the java SE 8 file from oracle website.  2. I created a folder called java in opt and extracted the downloaded tar ball into that file.  3. then I took a terminal and typed this  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java 100   4.then I configged java and selected the correct location. 5. then I updated the java home variables in etc/environment as JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_231
JRE_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_231/jre.  all these steps worked correctly.  but at the end when type java --version it says permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving executable permission to java using chmod.

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
```

where '/usr/bin/java' is the java path.